# Pi matching off-board antenna with module pigtail

Tags: pcb, rf, antenna, vna

I have an Iridium 9603 satellite modem integrated in a project and would like to tune its antenna feed line using a pi matching circuit on my carrier PCB. What's unique about this situation is that the Iridium module's antenna feeds through a short (~76mm) u.fl coax connected to the carrier, a PCB transmission line + pi matching circuit and then another mmcx coax into the antenna. *I've attached a photo for reference.*

I have a VNA and have successfully used it to tune simple chip antennas in the past - I am by no means an RF engineer though so I'm sorry if this is a silly question. Where should I place the feed point for the VNA and should I take special care to factor in transmission loses? My instinct would be to calibrate the VNA, port extend to the u.fl feed point labeled (**2**) and do a standard tuning, but I'm worried about not including the u.fl coax transmission line in my measurements.

Should I instead find a way to isolate and feed in to the u.fl connector on the 9603 module?

[image: Iridium 9603N carrier w/ Antenna]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve or establish? Is it a performance thing? Is it broken? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Its performance, the unmatched antenna performs very poorly compared to a similar system I've tested w/ matching.

Comment: Test it at point (2a) <-- top right connector on the upper PCB <-- unscrew the antenna and check the impedance into the antenna. Then check that the pi network component values are suitable for the impedance measured.

Comment: I may be missing something here - should I unscrew the antenna and measure impedance in the final enclosure as well? With my limited experience tuning chip antennas it's been very important to setup the test article with all plastics, bolts, etc. to ensure your tuning to the final environment. Wouldn't I be missing out on that without having the antenna in-circuit?

Comment: I said this: **check the impedance into the antenna**